# How to make the application to remember the boolean value?

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to add a sort of option window to my application using JOptionPane. If you click yes, a boolean is true. If you click no, a boolean is false and if you click the last button, I want another boolean to say false. And whenever that last button is clicked, I want that window to never be popped up again.

This is my code at the moment.

```
        if (Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC) {
            Object[] options = {"Yes",
                                "No",
                                "No, don't ask me again!"};
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "Would you like to play the login music?",
                "Login music",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[2]);
            if (n == 0) {
                Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC = true;
            } else if (n == 1){
                Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC = false;  
            } else {
                Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC_NEVER = true;
                Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC = false;              
                System.out.println("cancel");
                System.out.println(Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC_NEVER);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            if (Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC_NEVER == false) {
                checkForLoginMusic();
            }
                //System.out.println("The login music has been " + (Configuration.LOGIN_MUSIC ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
                nodeID = 10;
                portOff = 0;
                setHighMem();
                signlink.startpriv(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
                clientSize = 0;
                instance = new Client();
                instance.createClientFrame(clientWidth, clientHeight);
                //instance = new Jframe(args, clientWidth, clientHeight, false); uncomment if i want to add back the menu bar at top
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }

    }
```

Comment: you mean when you restart the application?

Comment: yes exactly what i meant.

Comment: Use some persistence, either [`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) (saves to file) or [`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/PreferencesFactory.html) (saves to hidden storage on your computer)

Comment: or save it in a db

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Why does your link lead to `java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory` instead?

Comment: Thank you!! Got it all working :)